# Symonfy2 validation: define constraints in yml, and validate an array

Tags: php, forms, validation, symfony

All I am trying to do is:

1. define constraints in yml
2. use this to validate an array

Say, a product array:

```
$product['name'] = 'A book';
$product['date'] = '2012-09';
$product['price'] = '21.5';
```

How to do that?

Answer (score 4):

First of all, you need to know that Symfony2 validators are not ready to do that easily. It took me some time and some Symfony2 source reading to get a working solution for your case, and my solution is not that natural.

I made a class that takes the validator, your array, and your yaml configuration file so you'll be able to do what you expect. This class extends the `YamlFileLoader` from Symfony to access the protected `parseNodes` method : this is not beautiful but that's the only way I found to transform a custom Yaml configuration file into an array of `Constraint` object.

So here we are. I give you my code, you'll need to replace some namespaces according to your own context.

First, create a controller for our demo :

```
    public function indexAction()
    {

        // We create a sample validation file for the demo
        $demo = <<< EOT
name:
    - NotBlank: ~
    - MinLength: { limit: 3 }
    - MaxLength: { limit: 10 }
date:
    - NotBlank: ~
    - Regex: "/^[0-9]{4}\-[0-9]{2}$/"
price:
    - Min: 0

EOT;
        file_put_contents("/tmp/test.yml", $demo);

        // We create your array to validate
        $product = array ();
        $product['name'] = 'A book';
        $product['date'] = '2012-09';
        $product['price'] = '21.5';

        $validator = $this->get('validator');
        $service = new \Fuz\TestsBundle\Services\ArrayValidator($validator, $product, "/tmp/test.yml");
        $errors = $service->validate();

        echo '<pre>';
        var_dump($errors);
        die();

        return $this->render('FuzTestsBundle:Default:index.html.twig');
    }
```

Then create a class named ArrayValidator.php. Again, take care of the namespace.

```
<?php

namespace Fuz\TestsBundle\Services;

use Symfony\Component\Validator\ValidatorInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Yaml\Parser;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Mapping\Loader\YamlFileLoader;

/**
 * This class inherits from YamlFileLoader because we need to call the
 * parseNodes() protected method.
 */
class ArrayValidator extends YamlFileLoader
{

    /* the @validator service */
    private $validator;

    /* The array to check */
    private $array;

    /* The file that contains your validation rules */
    private $validationFile;

    public function __construct(ValidatorInterface $validator, array $array = array(), $validationFile)
    {
        $this->validator = $validator;
        $this->array = $array;
        $this->validationFile = $validationFile;
    }

    /* The method that does what you want */
    public function validate()
    {
        $yaml = file_get_contents($this->validationFile);

        // We parse the yaml validation file
        $parser = new Parser();
        $parsedYaml = $parser->parse($yaml);

        // We transform this validation array to a Constraint array
        $arrayConstraints = $this->parseNodes($parsedYaml);

        // For each elements of the array, we execute the validation
        $errors = array();
        foreach ($this->array as $key => $value)
        {
            $errors[$key] = array();

            // If the array key (eg: price) has validation rules, we check the value
            if (isset($arrayConstraints[$key]))
            {
                foreach ($arrayConstraints[$key] as $constraint)
                {
                    // If there is constraint violations, we list messages
                    $violationList = $this->validator->validateValue($value, $constraint);
                    if (count($violationList) > 0)
                    {
                        foreach ($violationList as $violation)
                        {
                            $errors[$key][] = $violation->getMessage();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return $errors;
    }

}
```

Finally, test it with different values in your $product array.

By default :

```
        $product = array ();
        $product['name'] = 'A book';
        $product['date'] = '2012-09';
        $product['price'] = '21.5';
```

Will display :

```
array(3) {
  ["name"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["date"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["price"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
}
```

If we change values to :

```
    $product = array ();
    $product['name'] = 'A very interesting book';
    $product['date'] = '2012-09-03';
    $product['price'] = '-21.5';
```

You'll get :

```
array(3) {
  ["name"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(61) "This value is too long. It should have 10 characters or less."
  }
  ["date"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(24) "This value is not valid."
  }
  ["price"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(31) "This value should be 0 or more."
  }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: thank you, this is a great answer/explanation. God bless you;)

Answer (score 1):

the way to validate an array is easy, I've learned it in [silex documentation](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/providers/validator.html)

```
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

...
...

$constraint = new Assert\Collection(array(
    'Name' => new Assert\MinLength(10),
    'author' => new Assert\Collection(array(
        'first_name' => array(new Assert\NotBlank(), new Assert\MinLength(10)),
        'last_name'  => new Assert\MinLength(10),
    )),
));
$errors = $this->get('validator')->validateValue($book, $constraint);
```

or you can create directly forms with constraints

```
$form = $this->get('form.factory')->createBuilder('form',array(),array(
    'csrf_protection'       => false,
    'validation_constraint' => new Assert\Collection(array(
        'name'       => new Assert\NotBlank(array(
            'message' => 'Can\'t be null'
        )),
        'email'      => new Assert\Email(array(
            'message' => 'Invalid email'
        )),
    ))
))
->add('name', 'text')
->add('email', 'email')
->getForm();

}
```

this code can solve your second point but for the first point i suggest you to write a custom class that transforms your yaml definition to a valid constraints array with instantiated validation constraint objects or maybe that gives directly a form!

I don't know of a class ready to do this in symfony2.

I've done it in other projects that do not have a good data model, but in symfony you can create your models and define the validation associated with it.

Comment: Thank you but is that possible to define constraints in yml?

Comment: As you can see the constraints are a simple array of objects, you can define this array in a yaml file, then load the yaml file to array and instantiate the objects by their names. I'm sorry but you need to do it with a custom class/method that you need to create, I told you just how it should be:)

Answer (score -1):

in your validation.yml:

```
Acme\DemoBundle\Entity\AcmeEntity:
    properties:
        price:
            - NotBlank: ~
            - Acme\DemoBundle\Validator\Constraints\ContainsAlphanumeric: ~
```

and your ContainsAlphanumeric:

```
<?php
    namespace Acme\DemoBundle\Validator\Constraints;
    use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraint;
    use Symfony\Component\Validator\ConstraintValidator;

    class ContainsAlphanumericValidator extends ConstraintValidator
    {
        public function validate($value, Constraint $constraint)
        {
            if (!preg_match('/^[a-zA-Za0-9]+$/', $value, $matches)) {
                $this->context->addViolation($constraint->message, array('%string%' => $value));
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: This is for validating an entity object, not what I want